# NLB routing request to different destination IP of a websocket server running on exactly one pod

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, websocket, amazon-eks, nlb

I've a websocket server running at port 5001 on exactly one pod in k8s. When I downloaded the log from load balancer(NLB), I notice that different destination IP address for the service. Shouldn't there be only one IP address assign to the pod. There's only one replica of the pod and checking the k8s dashboard, I also verified that the pod hasn't restarted/deployed in last 28 days.

```
grep -oE '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+:[0-9]+' nlb_log.txt | awk -F: '$2 == 5001 {print $1}' | sort -u

192.168.109.191
192.168.152.123
192.168.206.158
```

This is the details of my pod in k8s dashboards:

```
Kind: replicaset
Pods: 1 / 1
Age: 28 days ago

Resource information
Node: ip-192-168-161-222.us-west-2.compute.internal
Status: Running
IP: 192.168.141.175
QoS Class: BestEffort
Restarts: 0
Service Account: default
```

So, want to understand where is NLB getting these IPs.